# Arduino fan controller code issues (LM35)

Tags: arduino

I got an issue with the PWM signal on the fan, it actually gets to 100% right away when it hits 21°C when it should be on 10%. I don't think it's a circuit issue, so any suggestions on the code ? I am pretty sure the problem is somewhere at the Map function, just can't seem to figure it out.

[image]

```cpp
 #include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(12,11,5,4,3,2);
int tempPin = A1;   // the output pin of LM35
int fan = 11;       // the pin where fan is
int led = 8;        // led pin
int temp;
int tempMin = 20;   // the temperature to start the fan
int tempMax = 30;   // the maximum temperature when fan is at 100%
int fanSpeed;
int fanLCD;

void setup() {
  pinMode(fan, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(tempPin, INPUT);
  lcd.begin(16,2);  
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {  
   temp = readTemp();     // get the temperature
   if(temp  < tempMin) { // if temp is lower than minimum temp 
      fanSpeed = 0; // fan is not spinning 
      digitalWrite(fan, LOW); 
   } 
   if((temp  >= tempMin) && (temp <= tempMax)) { // if temperature is higher than minimum temp 
      fanSpeed = map(temp, tempMin, tempMax, 115, 255); // the actual speed of fan 
      fanLCD = map(temp, tempMin, tempMax, 0, 100); // speed of fan to display on LCD 
      analogWrite(fan, fanSpeed); // spin the fan at the fanSpeed speed 
   } 
   if(temp  > tempMax) {        // if temp is higher than tempMax
     digitalWrite(led, HIGH);  // turn on led 
   } else {                    // else turn off led
     digitalWrite(led, LOW); 
   }

   lcd.print("TEMP: ");
   lcd.print(temp,1);      // display the temperature
   lcd.print("C ");
   lcd.setCursor(0,1);   // move cursor to next line
   lcd.print("FAN: ");
   lcd.print(fanLCD);    // display the fan speed
   lcd.print("%");
   delay(500);
   lcd.clear();   
}

int readTemp() {  // get the temperature and convert it to celsius
  temp = analogRead(tempPin);
  return (temp * 0.48828125)-48;
}
```

Comment: Your pins in the schematic don't match the pins in the code.

Comment: Which Arduino? For example on Uno you can't use pin 13 as HW PWM output. For the pins that aren't on timer is everything under 128 considered as LOW and rest is HIGH.

Comment: It's arduino Uno R3, i am using pin 6 (it has "~" next to it which indicates PWM right?).

Comment: @gre_gor yes, i used different pins on the actual circuit , the connections are correct, changed the code though to avoid further confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so apparently there was a problem with this specific pin, i tried another one (PWM), and it worked perfectly!